# IllegalStateException textview cant be null with Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am trying to create a way to update the UI when activity starts by setting the text of a TextView in the navigation drawer. I keep getting an error that the TextView cannot be null?

The error I get is an illegal state Exception userEmail must not be null

This is the updateUI that  is supposed to update the profile info in the navigation drawer

```
private fun updateUI(user:FirebaseUser?) {
   if (user != null) {
   val userEmailText = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.userEmail)
   userEmail.text = user.email
   val errorTriage : String? = user.email
   println("User Email is ="+errorTriage)
   } else {
val userEmailText: TextView = findViewById(R.id.userEmail)

   userEmailText.text = "Johndoe@someemail.com"
   userNameText.text = "John Doe"

   }}
```

This is the call to UpdateUI if user is signed in if so update profile data in navigation drawer THIS IS WHeRE THE ISsUE IS. If not it starts the FirebaseUI signin activity.

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    //Checks to see if user is already signed in
    if (mAuth.currentUser != null) {
        updateUI(mAuth.currentUser)
   } else {
        //user is not signed in
        startActivityForResult(
  AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder().build(),
                RC_SIGN_IN)
   }}
```

This is the layout

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="Android Studio"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />
  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userEmail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

Comment: Are you certain that `findViewById(R.id.userEmail)` is finding the view you need? Also, would you clarify where exactly the error occurs?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Update! So I have figured out that it works just fine on first install and sign in but for some reason if after initial sign in you close the app when you open it it crashes at the updateUI part. I wander if it has something to do with if user is already signed in it can’t update. I might try a shared preference and save user name and email and just wipe that on sign out.

**EDIT**
This was a question from a long time ago,  but what it was,  was one I hate the correct variable I then needed to call from onCreate and onStart. At the time of asking this question I was struggling working just the idea of coding let alone the concept of the Android lifecycle. There had also been a known issue with the way you used to initialize views in a navigation header. Once you initialize the navigation drawer view you then initialize the navigation drawer header then can initialize the textviews within.

Comment: Anyone have an idea why the TextView would say that data string is null but logcat would display correctly

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I was working on this all night and posted the pissed off code lol. I updated the code to what the issue was. Also I just realized that I named the value userEmailText and was trying to set

```
userEmail.text = user.email
```

Instead of

```
userEmailText.text = user.email
```

That would explain why when I did println it would show it log cat correctly

Comment: I’ll test this code and if works I will mark it so. I am currently on my phone.

Comment: Just confirmed this was the problem. Just goes to show how delicate spelling is.